# How to get rid of the Youtube Notifications "Close" button?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, youtube, notifications

I've scoured the internet and starting to feel like I'm the only one that's actually getting this because there's absolutely no information about it or how to change it. To turn on the notifications in the first place, I followed the the instructions provided by Youtube and that's mirrored on any number of sites on the subject. Turning on notifications in my Youtube account and allowing them through Chrome, which is fully updated to the most current stable version.

The issue is that Youtube Notifications on Windows 10 1903 seem to behave like no other.

First, there’s a close button on them, so when a notification pops up about someone live streaming, a new video or reply to a comment it stays on screen until I click the notification to watch the video/reply or click the close button. There doesn’t seem to be anyway to change the thing. I want the notifications, but I want them to dismiss if I don’t interact with them. Just like any other notification that might pop up in windows 10.

Second, Youtube notifications seem like they can take it upon themselves to ignore the gaming or fullscreen settings for notifications. When playing a game or watching a movie or running any application fullscreen, Windows 10 suppresses notifications. Once you leave fullscreen, Windows 10 notifies you about notifications that came in while you were busy. Not Youtube notifications though! Youtube is above things like that and notifications will pop-up in the middle of a game or movie and of course stay there until I click the close button. The problem is even worse if it's a game that can't be paused or doesn't like to be ALT-TABBED.

Third and finally, all the above is annoying as it is. A work around was to set Focus Assist to Alarms Only while you gamed or watched a movie. Except that no good things last forever, and Youtube Notifications have decided to ignore that setting too.

I've posted several times in Chrome and Youtube Support forums, but never even got a reply. I think I've even posted in Windows 10's Feedback Hub.
I haven't been able to find any information about this, so my question would be: How do I get my Youtube Notifications to behave like everyone else's? I know I can disable them completely, but would like to avoid that.

I'd like to just remove the close button and have the Youtube Notifications behave like any other notifications in Windows 10, which is to have them dismiss after 5 or 3 seconds or whatever the default is for every other notification when not interacted with, and to always have them follow the Gaming and Fullscreen rules.

[image: Close Button on Youtube Reply Notification]

[image: Youtube Video Notification popping up during a fullscreen game]

Edited to add information from the comments as requested.

Comment: What did you install/turn on to enable these notifications?

Comment: Nothing. Just turned on Youtube notifications, which has you allow them through Google Chrome. Basically, I did exactly as Youtube's own instructions or any website that parrots them say to do.

When the feature first rolled out they were fine, then at some point (I think after a Chrome update) this close button appeared.

I've even posted in Google and Youtube's support forums about it and never even got a response.

Comment: Please include this information in your post.